# Accurate and Concise Translation of Dhamma Qualities

Tags: theravada, pali, translation

The common stanza describing qualities of dhamma goes as "Swakkatho bhagawatho dhammo sandittiko..." which describes six of them. I am looking for an accurate and concise translation of this from someone good in both Pali and English; and of course Buddhism

Comment: This sounds & doesn't sound like what you are looking for: Properties of Dhamma:
1. Steadfastness of the Dhamma
2. The orderliness of the Dhamma
3. All processes are inconstant, suffering, and all phenomena are not-self
(from Iti. 51) From "The complete Book of the Buddha's Lists

Answer (score 3):

There's one here -- [Dhammānussati](http://www.buddha-vacana.org/formulae/anussati.html#anussati-2):

> Svākkhāto bhagavatā dhammo: sandiṭṭhiko akāliko ehipassiko opaneyyiko paccattaṃ veditabbo viññūhī ti.

> The Dhamma is well declared by the Bhagavā: visible here and now, immediate, inviting to come and see, effective, to be individually ascertained by the wise.

If you use a mouse to hover over one of the coloured words (of English or Pali) there's a popup containing a little definition of the Pali:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

“(1)Svakhato Bhagavata Dhammo, (2)Sanditthiko, (3)Akaliko,(4)Ehipassiko, (5)Opanayiko, (6)Paccattam Veditabbo Vennuhi ti.”

"(1)Well expounded is the Dhamma of the Exalted One, (2)visible here and  now, (3)immediately  effective, (4)inviting  one  to  come  and see, (5)leading onwards, (6)to be realized by the wise each for himself."

[Source](https://www.urbandharma.org/pdf/PDF_BuddhismCourse/17_%20Recollection%20of%20the%20Buddha,%20Dhamma%20&%20Sangha.pdf)
PDF Pg 16, The definitions are further explained in the book.